# jquery mobile - event showpage on every page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to capture every `showpage` event on every div with data-role=page in my web application (jquery 1.7.1, jquerymobile 1.1.0) to run a function InitPage();

So in a Global.js, i made this

```
$(".ui-page").live("pageshow", function () { InitPage(); });
```

But, i don't know why, on some pages it works, but in others doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) { InitPage(); });
```